# Связь с сервером из приложения

Tags: c

Здраствуйте, хотел узнать, как можно связать десктопное приложение с базой данных на сервере. Мне нужно, чтобы программа отправляла строку на сервер, и если она есть в базе, то отправляла true, если нет false. База данных не принципиальна. Помогите пожалуйста, просто никогда не связывал приложения с сервером, даже не знаю с помощью чего и как это делается.

Comment: Делается это при помощи библиотек для связи с базами данных, например. Для разных БД свои библиотеки.

Comment: Давать кому попало доступ к базе наружу - плохо. Лучше на любом доступном языке (php/perl/python/nodejs) сделать "ручку", и дальше с приложения с помощью curl или других http дергать.

Comment: А что Вы вообще про СУБД знаете? Судя по вопросу - не очень много. Вкратце: есть много разных программ, которые называются "серверами БД" т.к. они ОБСЛУЖИВАЮТ (сервис) запросы от других программ. Эти другие программы называются "Клиентами СУБД".  Для каждого конкретного типа сервера (MySQL / MSSQL / Oracl...) существуют свои специфические инструкции по написанию клиентов. И существуют специальные библиотеки для облегчения написания таких клиентов. Ваш вопрос слишком общ...